# Non-breaking space not working on Android

Tags: android, html

`&#160;` non-breaking space seems to work when given as text in XML. When assigning text dynamically, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
viewHolder.actualMessage.setText(model.getMessage() + Html.fromHtml(" &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;"));
```

How do I append a non-breaking space to a string and assign this to a `TextView`.

Comment: Please refer to this document: https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html.

Comment: My bad, now how should i append a non-breakable space?

Comment: You could try using `&nbsp;`, but I doubt it will work. The you could possibly switch to a WebView (which supports rich HTML, including CSS and JavaScript) instead of a TextView.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: A WebView will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `&#160;` (which is equal to `&nbsp;` or `&#xA0;`) escapes the non-breaking space for HTML, you can do this with Java directly as well. You would just use the unicode representation `"\u00A0"` in the string:

```
viewHolder.actualMessage.setText(model.getMessage() + " \u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0");
```

Comment: I tried with few changes, and now I am glad its working , Thankyou

Comment: @Jaykishan you should add your changes to the answer or at least mention what you did.